# Prestashop 1.7 generates path to assets without slashes

Tags: php, url, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

After migrating my site from localhost to external host, prestashop generates urls to CSS and JS such way `http://example.euthemesnewthemeassetscsstheme.css` instead of `http://example.eu/themes/newtheme/assets/css/theme.css`
All things i have done:

1. Created new prestashop store in my localhost.
2. Changed `Shop domain` and `SSL domain` in prestashop back office.
3. Copied files to ftp.
4. Exported ->imported database.
5. Edited `parameters.php`in order to point new database.

All other is fine, but urls goes wrong. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this trouble by changing in my `javascript.tpl` : from `{$js.uri}` to `{$urls.shop_domain_url}{$js.path}` and in `stylesheets.tpl` from `{$stylesheet.uri}` to `{$urls.shop_domain_url}{$stylesheet.path}`.
I know that i have just repaired view and that the controller is still have bug. I am interested in repairing Controller.